# How can I map a plugin-defined function call in a way that allows invocation with a count?

Tags: vim

In the Vimwiki source code, the following line maps the key `=` to the expression `<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel`.

```
nmap <silent><buffer> = <Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel
```

Unfortunately, this mapping does not work correctly with a count. In particular, typing `4=` appears to have the same effect as typing `=`.

Based on [this vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-mappings-that-accept-a-count/), I first attempted to use the expression register to rectify the mapping.

```
:nnoremap <buffer> = @=<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel<CR>
```

Unfortunately, when I type `=`, I get the following error.

```
E15: Invalid expression: <Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel
```

Next, I tried the `:normal` method.

```
:nnoremap <buffer> = :normal <Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel<CR>
```

This resulted in no errors when I type `=`, but also had no visible effect on the buffer. I also tried the recursive version of the mapping, but that had the same effect.

```
:nmap <buffer> = :normal <Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel<CR>
```

**What is the correct way to do the mapping so that it can accept a count?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (easily [1]) solve this in the mapping. The plugin's implementation has to support a count, and apparently, this one doesn't: `<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel` is mapped to `:<C-U>call vimwiki#base#AddHeaderLevel()<CR>`, so any count would result in an automatically prepended range, which `<C-U>` then removes. The `vimwiki#base#AddHeaderLevel()` function would have to pick up the count via `v:count` (or `v:count1`), but it doesn't.

Alternatively, the `:function` could be defined with the `range` attribute, and would then be passed `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`; cp. [`:help function-range-example`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#function-range-example). Or the `<C-U>` would have to be dropped, then the function would be called once per line.

So, if you think it makes sense to support a count, submit an issue (or pull request) to the project.

[1] Well, if the effect can be obtained by executing the mapping repeatedly at the same location, you could write a wrapper function with a `:for` loop on `v:count` that invokes the mapping via

```
:execute "normal \<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel"
```