# Is it possible to map to execute normal command?

Tags: vim

The following command appears to invoke the desired function.

```
:execute "normal \<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel<CR>"
```

However, putting it inside a mapping seems to cause problems.

```
:nmap <buffer> = execute "normal \<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel<CR>"
```

Here's the output when I type `=`.

```
E114: Missing quote: "normal \<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel
E15: Invalid expression: "normal \<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel
```

**Is there some special syntax that would allow me to perform this mapping?**

Comment: Isn't it just `nmap <buffer> = <Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel`?

Comment: @Ralf, Please take the question at face value.
The problem with the command you suggested is that it does not handle counts correctly. More specifically, `5=` doesn't actually perform the operation 5 times.

Comment: That's why I added a comment, not an answer. Another question: Do you really need the `<cr>` at the end? I tested another `<Plug>` mapping (i don't have VimWiki), and I didn't need it.

Comment: @Ralf, I'm not sure, but it seemed to be necessary for the first command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You don't enter *command-line mode* (for `:execute`) from the *normal mode* mapping; the `:` is missing.
- The `<Plug>` and `<CR>` are already evaluated by the mapping; the double quotes do not protect them. The `<CR>` submits the (incomplete, as Vim hasn't seen the trailing `"`) command-line, and that causes the `E114`.
- After escaping `<` as `<lt>`, you still need another `<CR>` to conclude the `:execute` command.

```
:nmap <buffer> = :execute "normal \<lt>Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel\<lt>CR>"<CR>
```

As I've noted in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637491/how-can-i-map-a-plugin-defined-function-call-in-a-way-that-allows-invocation-wit/54647475#54647475), you need a `:for` loop if you really want to work around the plugin's failure to accept a count. Though it would be possible to do all that inline in the mapping's right-hand side, separating the loop into a separate `:function` is highly recommended, exactly to avoid such escaping issues. Inside a function, the plugin invocation is a simple

```
:execute "normal \<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel"
```